# Why the content is not displaying when ng-content is used?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, ng-content, angular-component-life-cycle

We know that the app-root component selector is used in the index.html file. So I placed some content between the selector. So to access the content I used ng-content inside the app-root HTML file. but the content is not displayed in the browser. It shows some strange behavior

index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project1</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>
    <h1>Hello this is from app-root</h1>
  </app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.html:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I am expecting <h1> content should be displayed on the browser, but it is not happening why?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<ng-content></ng-content>` from app.component.html and  content should be displayed on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check this SO about [structure of index.html in an angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245404/structure-of-an-angular-project-file-index-html/75245866#75245866).

So the "tag" in index.html (and what-ever inside) are always replace by the component.

You need to have a component app-home

```
  <ng-content></ng-content>
```

And your app-root

```
<app-home>
    <h1>Hello this is from app-root</h1>
</app-home>
```